# Text below images in css grid is making them change size based on length of text

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm a bit new to front end and doing my best to figure things out. I have been building a relatively simple landing page and all looking great except when I try to use a css grid.  The text (people's names) is changing the size of the images so that none of them are the same size (see the attached image).  It seems that the images directly above and below each other grow together if the text is changed for one. While the images next to each other left and right change inversely. Removing all text makes them the same size.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/BrendenG/24vroqLu/9/) is a fiddle for a runnable copy.

[image: CSS grid issue]

I would really like to set the grid to take up a percentage of the container it's in if it's possible. For the life of me I can't find what I am missing. Is there some way that I can set all images to stay the same size as one another?

I will try to include the relevant pieces of CSS.

```css
.team {
  padding: 66px 0 80px 0;
  background-image: url("assets/pattern-team.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
}

.team .container {
  display: flex;
}

.team-heading {
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

.team-heading p {
  margin-top: 17px;
}

.team-members {
  width: 70%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "name1." "name2 name3";
  gap: 30px;
  row-gap: 30px;
}

.name1 {
  grid-area: name1;
}

.name2 {
  grid-area: name2;
}

.name3 {
  grid-area: name3;
}

enter code here .team-member {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.team-member .team-img {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px #7CE04E;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.team-member h4 {
  margin: 15px 0 5px 0;
}

.team img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Our team -->
<section class="team">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="team-heading">
      <h2>Our team</h2>
      <p>Meet the cats behind the magic.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="team-members">
      <!-- Griff -->
      <div class="team-member griff">
        <div>
          <img class="team-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Solid_red.svg" />
        </div>
        <h4>Griff</h4>
        <p>description</p>
      </div>
      <!-- Brenden -->
      <div class="team-member brenden">
        <div>
          <img class="team-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Solid_red.svg" />
        </div>
        <h4>Brenden</h4>
        <p>description</p>
      </div>
      <!-- Thu -->
      <div class="team-member thu">
        <div>
          <img class="team-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Solid_red.svg" />
        </div>
        <h4>Thu</h4>
        <p>description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers or even a suggestion of where to start searching!

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML, preferably in a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth Okay I have added the html and linked to github for a runnable copy of it. Thanks!

Comment: I made a snippet of the code but it does not seem to reproduce this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add column templates:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
```

```css
h4 {
  font-size: 33px;
  line-height: 43px;
}

.team {
  padding: 66px 0 80px 0;
  background-image: url("assets/pattern-team.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
}
.team .container {
  display: flex;
}

.team-heading {
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 80px;
}
.team-heading p {
  margin-top: 17px;
}

.team-members {
  width: 70%;
  display: grid;
  /*Set 2 eqaul columns*/
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "griff ." "brenden thu";
  gap: 30px;
  row-gap: 30px;
}

.griff {
  grid-area: griff;
}

.brenden {
  grid-area: brenden;
}

.thu {
  grid-area: thu;
}

.team-member .team-img {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px #7CE04E;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.team-member h4 {
  margin: 15px 0 5px 0;
}

.team img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Our team -->
<section class="team">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="team-heading">
      <h2>Our team</h2>
      <p>Meet the cats behind the magic.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="team-members">

      <!-- Griff -->
      <div class="team-member griff">
        <div>
          <img
               class="team-img"
               src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Solid_red.svg"
               />
        </div>
        <h4>Griff</h4>
        <p>description</p>
      </div>

      <!-- Brenden -->
      <div class="team-member brenden">
        <div>
          <img
               class="team-img"
               src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Solid_red.svg"
               />
        </div>
        <h4>Brenden</h4>
        <p>description</p>
      </div>

      <!-- Thu -->
      <div class="team-member thu">
        <div>
          <img class="team-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Solid_red.svg"/>
        </div>
        <h4>Thu</h4>
        <p>description</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: THANK YOU. Yes that has fixed everything!